# Calculating $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{p}{2} \rfloor} \binom{p}{k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to find the value of: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{p}{2} \right \rfloor} \binom{p}{k}$$ For even and odd $p$, the indication I was given suggests writing it as $$\frac{1}{2}\left (\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{p}{2} \right \rfloor} \binom{p}{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{p}{2} \right \rfloor} \binom{p}{p-k} \right )$$ But I nothing I did got me anywhere.

Comment: Recall that $\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}=(1+1)^k$.

Comment: Look at Pascal's triangle. The p-th row consists of the values $p \choose k$. Maybe you can notice a pattern when you sum 1/2 the values in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an excellent suggestion! Ceiling and floor functions are awkward, so my first step is always to remove them somehow:

**Even $p$**

For even $p$, we can define $p=2m$. Then the suggestion given to you become:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{k}
+
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{2m-k}
\right)
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m}{k}
+
\sum_{k=m}^{2m}\binom{2m}{k}
\right)
\\\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\binom{2m}{m}+\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{k}
\right)
\\\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\binom{p}{\frac{p}{2}}+2^{p}
\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

**Odd $p$**

We define $p=2m+1$. Then the suggestion becomes:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{k}
+
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{2m+1-k}
\right)
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{2m+1}{k}
+
\sum_{k=m+1}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{k}
\right)
\\\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{k}
\right)
\\\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2^{p}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Key Points**

- Always try to use the suggestion given to you by lecturer / book
- If an integer is odd or even, translate it to the equation using $p=2m$ or $p=2m+1$
- When there is a summation, try to change the index of summation
- Be familiar with binomial coefficients and their various well-known properties

Comment: This question was back in my high school years! I had completely forgotten it ever exited. How on Earth did you find it? Anyhow, really nice write-up :)

Comment: @fuzzypixelz yesterday, someone answered the question so it appeared in my recommendation :D

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & 2^{\,p}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,p} {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor  + 1\, \le \,k\, \le \,p} {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor  + 1\, \le \,k\, \le \,p} {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  p - k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,p - \left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lceil {{p \over 2}} \right\rceil  - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lceil {{p \over 2}} \right\rceil  - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{\left\lceil {{p \over 2}} \right\rceil \, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lceil {{p \over 2}} \right\rceil  - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \left( {\left\lceil {{p \over 2}} \right\rceil  - \left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor  - 1} \right)\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  \left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 2\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,\left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  - \left( {1 - p\bmod 2} \right)\left( \matrix{
  p \cr 
  \left\lfloor {{p \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$